# Meteor: How to develop multiple webservers with Reactive DOTW

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I am currently looking at possible development models for a device that will be in a clients home. I need the device to run a local copy of Meteor while also being able to get and insert information from a central server in a secure/reactive way.

[image: Basic information]

All sensitive information has not been included in this image

I am required to make a local server as I need to run shell commands on the device. While the device could make HTTP webhook calls, it would be slow due to packet travel time and does not meet requirements.

I know that the local server could connect to the Central Server mongodb which would be ideal, however as this local server is physically located in a clients house, this means that the mongodb password would be exposed (big security problem). Also I would be unable to control what information is sent to the local server. I was unable to find a way to subscribe to an external server, which would be a great solution.

Another way could be that the local server simply use HTTP requests, however another requirement is that Audit requests appear almost as soon as they are issued which is ideal for a reactive mongodb item. A heartbeat wouldn't really fit due to the data/processing overheads and slowness.

The summary the question is: How to make a device to run a local copy of Meteor while also being able to get and insert information from a central server in a secure/reactive way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well in the end, I found that you can use cross-server and even CORS connections with https://docs.meteor.com/api/connections.html

So now any aspiring developer can use the DDP framework.